# PHP HTML Contact Form

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form on a website thats uses a php script to send the details to my email.

The issue i'm having is that the data from the First Name field is not sending to my email at all.

I have a feeling this will be a really obvious mistake, but I cannot seem to find the error!

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $ToEmail = 'myemail@mycompany.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'BGM Contact Form'; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "First Name: ".$_POST["firstName"].""; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Last Name: ".$_POST["lastName"].""; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["message"]).""; 
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="thankyou.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <label class="inline">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-10 columns">
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <label class="inline">Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-10 columns">
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Smith" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="large-2 columns">
            <label class="inline" > Your Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-10 columns">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="yourEmail" placeholder="jane@smithco.com" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label>Your Message</label>
    <textarea rows="8" name="message" required></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="radius button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your orverriding the "firstName" value, chnage the code to $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Last Name: ".$_POST["lastName"]."";  --- notice the dot before the equals sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following by replacing `".` with a single quote `"`

```
<?php 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "First Name: '$_POST["firstName"]'"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Last Name: '$_POST["lastName"]'"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: '$_POST["email"]'"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: 'nl2br($_POST["message"])'"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is here

```
$MESSAGE_BODY = "First Name: ".$_POST["firstName"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Last Name: ".$_POST["lastName"]."";
```

Change it to

```
$MESSAGE_BODY = "First Name: ".$_POST["firstName"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Last Name: ".$_POST["lastName"]."";
```

You are overriding the first $MESSAGE_BODY that contains firstName

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your php script

```
$ToEmail = 'myemail@mycompany.com'; 
        $EmailSubject = 'BGM Contact Form'; 
        $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
        $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
        $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY = "First Name: ".$_POST["firstName"].""; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Last Name: ".$_POST["lastName"].""; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["message"]).""; 
        mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
```

use the above php script